# Core i9 performs poorly with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I have a workstation running Ubuntu 14.04 with kernel version 4.4. It's got a core i9-7900x and a GTX 1080ti graphics card.

Unfortunately, the system runs very poorly under load, particularly when there are many processes running at once. Under these conditions, the rest of the system becomes unresponsive -- i.e., clicking on things can take seconds to respond. Other systems, with slower hardware, don't have this problem under the same load.

Anyone have an idea what could be causing this? I suspect the older Ubuntu or kernel version may not support the i9-7800x well, does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Upgrade to 16.04.3?

Comment: Try intel's [linpack benchmark](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-benchmarks-suite) with 10000x10000 matrices. Monitor stability and temperatures during test. It should give at least 150 GFLOPS. Then update kernel to the xenial's version and compare.

Comment: @N0rber -- good thinking on linpack for benchmarks

Comment: @dobey Wish I could, unfortunately I have to stick to 14.04 for compatibility with other stuff

Comment: Did you install with 14.04.5? Or are you on the original 14.04? Compatibility with what? You can install 16.04.3, which gets you kernel 4.10, and then if there's something you must run that only works on 14.04 for some reason, run it in a container/vm on top.

Comment: I would suggest you use 16.04 which has newer kernels which would allow for better compatibility with the most recent processors.

Answer (score 2):

This was solved by upgrading to kernel 4.12.14. Instructions for updating the kernel in Ubuntu can be found here: [How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade)