# Nvidia drivers Create Login Loop on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, kernel, login

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 because the primary software I use for work depends on this version. The Nvidia-390 was installed and running fine, but the computer was slow (likely due to an i9 chip, as [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984766/core-i9-performs-poorly-with-ubuntu-14-04) poses). To solve the problem, I updated the kernel from Linux 4.4 to Linux 4.14, which is past what Ubuntu 14.04 will automatically install to.

Upon reboot, his created the infamous login loop where typing in the password gives a black screen and then returns to the login screen. I used `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` and reset to login again. I reinstalled trying nvidia-390/396/340 and 384 using [this guide](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-linux) and I have the same problem. Now, even if I boot back into Linux 4.4, the issue persists. Running `nvidia-smi` returns `NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running`.

Here are some of the specs for the system that may or may not be relevant:

- Computer: Apexx X3
- Motherboard: Gigabyte X299
- Chip: i9-7980XE chip
- OS: Ubuntu 14.04.5
- GPU: Nvidia GTX 1080ti
- Graphics Driver: nvidia-390
- Kernel: 4.14.35
- Dual-boot with Windows 10

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: The driver doesn't build for this kernel.

Comment: @Pilot6 But even when I revert to 4.4 now, it still doesn't work.